# finding the occurance of strings in python

Tags: python, string, text, find, beautifulsoup

I have a long string which I have parsed through beautifulsoup and I need advice on the best way to extract data from this soup object.

The number I want is contained inside the soup object, inside () after this text.

View All (8)

What is the most efficient way to locate this, and get the number out of it.

In VBA I would have done this.

(1) Find where does this text string start if soup is length 1000 text is at 200

Then I would loop until I found the ending ), grab that text, store it in a variable, and process each character removing everything which is not a number.

So If I have > View All (8)  I would end up with **8**. The  number inside here is not known, could be q00, 110, or 2000.

I have just started learning python, don't yet know how to use regular expression but that seems the way to go?

**Sample String**

```
">View All (90)</a>
```

**Expected Result - hopeful**

```
90
```

**Sample String**

```
">View All (8)</a>
```

**Expected Result - hopeful**

```
8
```

Comment: `m = re.compile(r'View All \((\d*?)\)').search(soupstring); print m.group(1)`

Comment: Thanks Hans, 

I vaguelly understand re.compile, 

What does the following parts of the expression mean:

r' = treat as raw text?

is .search a string method or a method of re.compile?

where can I found out about the .group method and what it does? m stores all of the occurances of a number inside of brackets, and m.group(1) prints the first one?

why is there a slash \ outside of the expression. ((\d*?)\)

Is there somewhere you would recommend so I can learn what the symbols (/d*? mean when it comes to regular expressions?

Comment: @yoshiserry What about sample string and expected result? This might become a higway to expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how my comment provoked some more questions, let me expand it a bit. First, welcome to the wonderful world of regular expressions. Regular expressions can be quite a headache, but mastering them is a very useful skill. A very clear tutorial was written by A.M. Kuchling, one of Python's old hackers from the early days. If memory serves me he wrote the `re` library, with (as an additional bonus) an undocumented implementation of lex in some 15 odd lines of python. But I digress. You can find the tutorial here. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Let me go over the expression bit by bit:

```
m = re.compile(r'View All \((\d*?)\)').search(soupstring); 
print m.group(1)
```

1. The `r` in front of the quotation marks it as a raw string in Python. Python will preprocess normal string literals, so that a backslash is interpreted as a special character. E.g. a `'\t'` in a string will be replaced by the tab character. Try `print '\'` to see what I mean. To include a `'\'` in a string you have to escape it like this `'\\'`.  This can be a problem as a backslash is also a escaping character for the regular expression engine. If you have to match patterns that contain backslashes, you will soon be writing patterns like this `'\\\\'`. Which can be fun . . . If you like 50 shades of grey, give it a try.
2. Inside the regular expression language: `'('` characters are special. They are used to group parts of the match together. Since you are only interested in the digits between the parentheses, I used a group to extract this data. Other special characters are `'{', '[', , '*', '?', '\'` and their matching counterparts. I am sure I have forgotten a few, but you can look them up.
3. With that information, the `'\('` will make more sense. Since I have escaped the `'('` it tells the regular expression parser to ignore the *special* meaning of `'('` and instead match it against a literal `'('` character.
4. The sequence `'\d'` is again special. An escaped `'\d'` means, do not interpret this as a literal `'d'`, but interpret it as "any digit character".
5. The `'*'` means take the last pattern and match it zero or more times.
6. The `'*?'` variant means, use "greedy matching". It means return the first possible match instead of finding the longest possible match. In the context of regular expressions greed is usually good. As Sebastian has noted, the `'?'` is not needed here. However, if you ever need to find html elements or quoted strings, then you can use `'<.*?>'` or `'".*?"'`.
7. Please note that `'.'` is again special. It means match "any character (except the newline (well most of the time anyway))".

Have fun . . .

Comment: WOW Thanks for the great detail HANS I really appreciate it. I wish more people took the time to explain their answers the way you have. It helps so much! Now not only do I have the answer but I understand how it was achieved and why it works.

Comment: can you explain the regular expression .group function a little more. So if I do found = pattern.search(s).group(1) I get say 8 but if I do found=pattern.search(s).group() I get "View All (8)" Why is that? Instead i thought .group(1) would return 8 if View All (8) was the only instance of View All found, and if there were two, then it would return say as above 8 90;

Comment: Anything inside `()` inside a pattern will be a group. You can see it as a submatch inside a match. So the first `()` will be `group(1)`, the second `()` will be `group(2)` etc. `group(0)` simply means the whole match and `group()` is short for `group(0)`. What you are looking for are multiple instances of a pattern inside a string. Check the docs for `finditer`.